# Is it possible to lock a single feature from editing in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, features, editing, add-in

We're developing an ArcMap addin. Now we need a way to lock a feature from editing/deleting. Is this possible with ArcObjects or do we have to create our own implementation of locking?

**Example:**

User A starts editing a feature X. The feature should now be locked from editing by everyone else until user A finishes his/her edit.

Comment: I've never used it, but maybe the [IRowEvents](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IRowEvents_Interface/0025000007w5000000/) interface it's what you need.

Comment: I seems that the IRowEvent only provides _after_ events, so it cannot be used in this case. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can I use the system tables **sde.SDE_state_locks** or **sde.SDE_object_locks** somehow?